# Jekyll don't print post title

Tags: jekyll

I don't want the page `title` to be displayed at the top of each page. It prints even though I do not output the `title` in the layout, nor in the page file.

But I need to specify the title (for the head title tag). I could use css, but I would prefer a Jekyllrb setting, if one exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether there's a setting for this depends on your theme, but most don't have one. But it's usually straightforward to add a conditional yourself for this, again depending on your theme.

For example, if your theme is minima, notice in `_layouts/page.html`:

```
<header class="post-header">
  <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
</header>
```

You could wrap this in a conditional like:

```
{% unless page.hide_header %}
  <header class="post-header">
    <h1 class="post-title">{{ page.title | escape }}</h1>
  </header>
{% endunless %}
```

Put your modified `_layouts/page.html` in your site so it overrides the theme's provided file.

Then just update the page meta to include `hide_header`:

```
---
title: My Page
layout: page
permalink: /my_page/
hide_header: true
---
```

Alternatively, if you *never* want to show the title, you can just delete the `<header></header>` bit from the `page.html` template.

Comment: I only made a `default.html` file (and only had that file in the `layout` folder) and specified `page` as `layout`. I assumed this applied the `default` layout, as `page` didn't exist and it also worked. The layout had been applied. But somehow also the `post-header` has been displayed. I fixed it, thanks